# pairs.panels function in R for specific correlations of columns in dataframe

Tags: r, correlation, psych

I have a very large data set and am attempting to find the correlation between a lot of different (and random) combinations of the data. For instance, I may want the correlation between the 3rd column with the 12th-15th columns, or the correlation between the 20th column with the 1st-4th columns, etc...

I am currently using pairs.panels() function from the psych library, but am unable to pinpoint the specific pairing of columns I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `df`, a dummy `data.frame` with 26 columns, each containing random values, so the correlations should be reasonably low for any pair of columns.

```
cols = lapply(1:26, function(dummy) runif(30))
df = do.call(data.frame, cols)
names(df) = LETTERS
```

If you want the correlation between column "X" and columns "A", "C", and "E", try `sapply` with the `cor` function.

```
sapply(df[c("A","C","E")], cor, df["X"])
```

Or use column numbers:

```
sapply(df[c(1,3,5)], cor, df[24])
```

If you want all the permutative combinations of correlations between two groups of columns, try:

```
firstGroup <- c(1,3,5,20)
secondGroup <- c(14,20,25)
combos <- expand.grid(firstGroup, secondGroup)
result <- mapply(cor, df[combos$Var1], df[combos$Var2])
resultAsMatrix <- matrix(result, nrow = length(firstGroup), dimnames = list(firstGroup, secondGroup))
```

To get:

```
> resultAsMatrix
            14         20          25
1  -0.22949844 -0.1527876 -0.11877405
3   0.23174965  0.0311125  0.33570756
5   0.01491815 -0.1263007 -0.16688800
20  0.18007802  1.0000000  0.04638838
```

EDIT:

@user20650 pointed out that the `cor` function has the capacity to compare two matrices built in.  So:

```
cor(df[firstGroup], df[secondGroup])
```

yields the matrix I created manually, above:

```
            N          T           Y
A -0.22949844 -0.1527876 -0.11877405
C  0.23174965  0.0311125  0.33570756
E  0.01491815 -0.1263007 -0.16688800
T  0.18007802  1.0000000  0.04638838
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for. thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @user20650, yup -- a more elegant solution.  Thanks for that!  I'll update my answer.